# DNS name for FTP server using Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

My domain name is my-domain.com

All my servers are hosted on AWS.

I have setup an FTP Server, which can be accessed through it's public IP: 1.2.3.4

I want to be able to access the FTP server through the following DNS name  ftp.my-domain.com

Is this possible? Would I be able to create an A record in Route 53, and map the FTP ip to ftp.my-domain.com?

Comment: Yep.  That's pretty much how DNS works whether you're running FTP or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [yoonix](https://serverfault.com/users/143703/yoonix) said *That's pretty much how DNS works*.

Now for AWS you can follow steps below

- Services -> Route 53 -> Hosted Zones
- Create hosted zone and add `my-domain.com` as domain
- Click on the new created zone
- Create Record Set with **Name**: `ftp` **Value**: `1.2.3.4` **Type**: A - IPv4 address (default)

Or better, create `CNAME` record pointing on you servers AWS name

Comment: thanks, are you able to explain how this can be done using CNAME please?

Comment: pretty much the same except for the last part you need to pick CNAME as **Type**, **Value** will be the AWS name of your server and **Name** ftp